# Software that makes the mouse jump to nearest clickable objects like buttons, fields, etc

Tags: windows, mouse

Is there a software that makes the mouse jump to nearest clickable objects like buttons, fields, etc? So if you begin to get close to the nearest one it would jump there and lock it for a bit?

Maybe even slow down your mouse movement by half once you are on a "clickable" object, that way you are less likely to move out of it's parameters accidently?

I think this software would be amazing and would be of interest to all audiences.

Comment: I don't see any real usage for such a functionality

Comment: @Mr.Alien Personally I think if it's done right, it would be used by everyone and become mainstream very quickly. Why wouldn't you want your mouse to move closer to a clickable item ... especially if you have an algorithm to increase this attraction if it was the only clickable item in the area. It's similar to Chrome on smartphones where it pops up a zoomed in picture of what your trying to click because it wasn't 100% sure which one you clicked (which is a great feature).

Answer (score 6):

Some dwell clicking software such as [SmartNAV](http://www.naturalpoint.com/smartnav/support/downloads.html) (free, Windows) has such option, called gravity:

[image]

(AFAIC found it useful for a few weeks, then back to no gravity)

Comment: Thanks this is great and exactly what I'm looking for. However I am getting an error message upon starting SmartNAV: "Could not connect with a SmartNAV camera! Mouse control will be disabled until a SmartNAV camera is plugged in."